# docker how do I make host scripts available inside a container

Tags: docker

I am working with a kalilinux-based docker container (dnraikes/kali-net).
I am developing some proprietary scripts to run various security tools against our in-house servers so I don't want to embed the scripts inside the docker image using either the `COPY` or `ADD` commands in my Dockerfile.

My scripts are in `~/scripts` on the docker host.
when I run the docker container with the command:

```
$ docker run -it -v /opt/scripts:~/scripts dnraikes/kali-net /bin/bash
```

Once inside the container, if I switch to `/opt` there is no scripts folder.

Also, any results from the scripts must be visible on the docker host after the container has been either killed or stopped.

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching the directory locations like this:

```
$ docker run -it -v /home/<username>/scripts:/opt/scripts dnraikes/kali-net /bin/bash
```

From the [documentation on volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/volume-shared-filesystems), `-v` takes `[host-src]:[container-dest]`.

Also note that `host-src` must be an absolute path so replace `~/scripts` by `/home/<username>/scripts` or the full path to your `scripts` directory.